# Сколько дней необходимо, чтобы сумма стала 0 при ежедневном вычитании определенного % на PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, как решить на PHP следующую задачу?

Есть переменная `numb` значение которой изначально равно `100`. Каждый день от значения этой переменной отнимается `0.18%`. Через сколько дней значение переменной `numb` станет равно `0` или ближе к `0`?.

Comment: Так тут математика. А где ваша формула расчёта? И попытки написать код?

Comment: @doox911 Так ведь в вопросе я написал дословно "Подскажите, как решить на PHP следующую задачу?". Я не написал "Как переделать формулу, чтобы она работала и т.п.". Есть задача, я попросил помочь решить ее на PHP. Не понимаю, в чем ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Oleg ваш вопрос имеет минимум связи с PHP так как он математический, как правильно заметил doox911. Не важно как это делается на PHP - для начала напишите формулу или алгоритм, а уже потом конвертируйте её в любой язык программирования.

Comment: Я вас успокою - 0 никогда не получится. А ближе к 0 значение станет на следующий день.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov ну он возможно не только математический. Если с точки зрения математики это бесконечно убывающая последовательность. С точки зрения php или другого языка, я думаю есть ограничение в виде дискретного представления числа. и когда-то последовательность остановится, т.к. будет достигнуто минимально возможное число, что процент будет давать 0. Хотя и вправду не вижу тут сложностей и связи конкретно с php

Answer (score 1):

0 никогда не станет, но можно посчитать, сколько итераций потребуется, учитывая какую точность вы хотите получить.

```
<?php
$start = 100;
$percent = (1-0.0018); /* Ваш процент */
$x = $start*$percent;
$epsilon = 0.1; /* здесь Ваша точность */
$index = 1; /* счетчик итераций */

while($x > $epsilon){
   $x = $x*$percent;
   $index++;
}
echo $index;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это бесконечно убывающая геометрическая прогрессия, первый член которой 100, далее -0.18* 100 и т.д. Сумму можно найти по формуле. Нулю или меньше нуля сумма не будет никогда